# Using Glue schema registry with MSK Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-glue, confluent-schema-registry, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I've been trying to create an MSK Connector and use Glue schema registry with it.
The configuration is as follows.

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
s3.region=eu-west-1
topics.dir=topics/dir
flush.size=200
tasks.max=2
s3.part.size=5242880
timezone=GMT
# value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://someIP:8081
key.converter.schemaName=my-topic-schema
locale=US
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat
value.converter.schemaName=my-topic-schema
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.StringConverter
s3.bucket.name=my-bucket
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.StringConverter
# key.converter.schema.registry.url==http://someIP:8081
partition.duration.ms=3600000
schema.compatibility=BACKWARD
topics=osb
value.converter.registry.name=Glue-Schema-Registry
key.converter.registry.name=Glue-Schema-Registry
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
rotate.schedule.interval.ms=0
path.format='year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH
timestamp.extractor=RecordField
timestamp.field=timestamp
```

First I was using the confluent schema registry running on an EC2 whose ip I added in "key/value.converter.schema.registry.url" field and it was working fine. Now I'm trying to use Glue Schema Registry. But I don't know how to connect the connector with Glue Schema Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes don't exist

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.StringConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.StringConverter
```

The `StringConverter` classname starts with `org.apache.kafka`

Similarly, looks like you've added a bunch of random converter properties, which aren't valid for the String or Confluent Avro converter, apart from the url

---

To use Glue, you'll need to use `AWSKafkaAvroConverter`, which is part of this repo,

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/tree/master/avro-kafkaconnect-converter

And is documented here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry-integrations.html#schema-registry-integrations-apache-kafka-connect